# Putty refuses to open serial ports and just dings

Tags: windows-10, putty, serial-port

There's a windows 10 machine on which Putty refuses to open serial ports. There's no error message, just a "ding" then I click on <kbd>Open</kbd>. Any ideas on how to debug this?

I have tried rebooting and updating Putty already. The USB to UART dongles I'm trying to use are working fine when connected to a Linux PC and queried with `screen /dev/ttyUSB0 115200`. I've tried several such dongles, but the one I really want to use is a genuine FTDI FT2232H, which looks perfectly fine in device manager, with correct drivers installed.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

OK, this one is rather stupid: I forgot to select the "Serial" radio-button on the Session tab and went straight to the Serial tab. Putty was still expecting an SSH connection and dinging because no IP address was given.

Comment: Really confusing interface

Comment: You are my hero!

Comment: This still hurts....